# фон ''подменю''

Tags: html, css, opencart

Помогите в opencart поменять фон ''подменю''(выпадающего списка) как-то хочу его выделить ...
http://russiasouvenir.ru/index.php?route=product/category&path=59
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

На любом пункте подменю - пкм - код элемента(devtools). Там вы увидите, какие стили применяются к данному элементу и в каком файле они находятся. Стандартно это **stylesheet.css** по адресу `catalog/view/theme/default/template/stylesheet

Для изменения стилей определённой упорядоченной группы элементов из набора, используйте псевдокласс nth-child. В вашем случае:

```
... li:nth-child(-n+3){
    //выберет первые три элемента в наборе
}
... li:nth-child(3){
    //выберет третий элемемент в наборе
}
... li:nth-child(n+4){
    //выберет все, кроме первых трёх
}    
... li:nth-child(odd){
    //выберет все нечётные
}
... li:nth-child(even){
    //выберет все чётные
}
```

[Вот хорошая статья по псевдоклассам](https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/)

Если же имеется устойчивое желание залесть в шаблон, то смотрите тут:

> site\catalog\view\theme\your_theme_name(default)\template\module\category.tpl

Это файл представления, формирующий левое(правое) меню категории. Там вы найдёте цикл, рисующий это меню.

**UPD:**

В вашем конкретном случае, это не выпадающее меню. Это герерация меню при переходе по ссылке. Вы нажимаете на категорию и происходит переход, при этом меню пересобирается заново. Ссылки подкатегорий в этом случае просто пункты меню, визуально отмеченные чёрточкой слева. Для того, что бы однозначно их идентифицировать, отредактируйте код в файле `site\catalog\view\theme\your_theme_name(default)\template\module\category.tpl`
Ищите такую строчку:
 `<?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>`
В этом цикле как раз и добавляются подкатегории в список меню категорий. В нутри цикла выводятся ссылки подменю.

Comment: Так меняеться сразу все, а задать отдельный класс чтоб потом его менять я не знаю где, не знаю где файл со структурой страницы

Comment: li:nth-child(-n+3){
    //выберет первые три элемента в наборе
}
Так они должны меняться при выпадении,после клика,а они выходит выбраны постоянно. Дописывал active, чет не помогает

Comment: Ну найду я и что дальше?  Где мне в 
<?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?> задать классы пыпадающему меню?